# Azure SQL Database vs Table Storage for Session state

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have read here and on other post and forums that the best place to save session state in Azure is AppFabric Cache, but I find that very expensive and would like to give a go to either table storage or a SQL database.

I read that a SQL database will be faster but I can't understand why it would be. Surely the SQL database will cache hot data in memory, but I would expect Table Storage to also do that (does it?). Otherwise I don't see why a SQL database would be faster at retrieving a row than Table Storage, in the end both are just retrieving data from a local disk based on a key. I would even expect that because Table Storage scales up well and automatically (vs a SQL databases that needs to be partitioned manually), it would be preferable as session state isn't a good candidate for local caching.

Does anyone have any experience or opinion on this?

thanks
Charles

Comment: If pricing is a consideration, may I suggest you look at In-Role Caching where a part of your Cloud Service VM is used for caching purpose or you could have a dedicated cache worker role. More information about this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh914161.aspx. HTH.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps even before this, do I really need a cache for session state? Typically, session cookie for instance can last several days, so they need to be saved in a durable storage form. It is preferable not to have to go to disk on every client request of course, but don't azure table storage cache hot data in memory? if that is the case then logically using table storage vs a cache (appfabric or In-Role) would only affect the first request?

Comment: It depends. If you're deploying your application as a cloud service, then using cache for session state management is the best option available today as in-proc session does not work there. Table storage may be caching hot data in it's memory (I'm not sure how that works) but for you, it would be a network call nonetheless which will cause latency + chances of encountering transient errors.

Comment: If I understand In-Role caching correctly, it is effectively using part of the VM for caching. But 1. there is no guarantee that the client will come back to the same cluster, which would result in the same network call than table storage. 2. the cache is not stored in durable format so if I deploy a new version of the code I would loose all session cookies. Am I missing something? Reading an article on table storage, it looks like one potential drawback vs cache is that writes are never cached, so if asp.net writes to the session state on every request, it will result in a disk write.

Comment: The ideal thing would be to not use session state at all. If you are writing a new app this is possible but on an existing app might be difficult if it heavily uses Session. In the rare cases I use session I store it in Blob storage.

Comment: How do you deal with authentication cookies then?

Comment: Forms Authentication doesn't need session.

Comment: Thanks. I had not realised Forms Authentication was storing data in the cookie instead of a session.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned AppFabric Cache, which is a retired service. Regarding SQL vs Table: There isn't really a right answer to this. If you want to spin up a SQL Database instance (running about $2.50 monthly for a Basic-tier database), you'll have 2GB to work with. With Table storage, you'll pay about $0.15 for the same storage. Then there is Redis cache, your own cache (such as memcached), Azure Managed Cache service, etc. Performance-wise, you'd need to do some benchmarking to see how each performs. Any of these would work with Virtual Machines, Cloud Services (web/worker roles), and Web Sites, as they all have very well-defined APIs and, if using ASP.NET MVC, good provider support. Each has different capacity limits and different pricing.

One thing with Table storage: each entity (row) is limited to 1MB, so if you're attempting to cache > 1MB per cache entry, you'll need to consider another option.

@Gaurav mentioned in-role cache. This is a great way to use extra memory in your web/worker role instances. However: It's limited to web/worker Cloud Services; it doesn't help with Web Sites or Virtual Machines. For those, you really need some type of independent cache provider.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it will be mostly tiny data, i.e. session cookies, usernames, stuff like that. But my understanding of asp.net session is that it read and writes at the beginning and end of every request, so doing network calls every time is not very efficient but I just can't see any way around that.